# ng-Class - multiple conditions and classes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I have been looking for examples of multiple conditions in ng-class but I can't find using the same terminology. Here is an example of what I want to achieve.

> ng-class="isSelected ? 'side_menu_link_active' :
>   'side_menu_link_disabled' , pageSelected =='lectures' ? 'link_active'
>   : 'link_disabled'"

Does anyone knows the correct syntax for this?
thanks.

Comment: see my updated answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want multiple conditions the syntax is:

```
ng-class=" {className: valueToCheckForTruthiness, otherClassName: otherValue  } "
```

Example using your class names:

```
ng-class="{side_menu_link_active: isSelected, side_menu_link_disabled: !isSelected, link_active: pageSelected == 'lectures', link_disabled: pageSelected != 'lectures'   }"
```

You can take this further and generate an object using a function:

```
$scope.classGenerator = function(isSelected, pageSelected){
     var obj = {};
     isSelected ? obj.side_menu_link_active=true : obj.side_menu_link_disabled = false;
     pageSelected == 'lectures' ? obj.link_active = true : obj.link_disabled = false;
     return obj;
}
ng-class="classGenerator(isSelected, pageSelected)"
```

Comment: just a thing to work for multiple items using this method needs a third variable ( isSelected, pageSelected, module) then compare pageSelected == module

Comment: There are many ways to work with ng-class, see the official docs for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by comma separation

```
<div ng-class="{'isClicked1' : click, 'isClicked2' :!click}">
```

See my  working **[jsfiidle](http://jsfiddle.net/nisham/mgPGS/97/)**